# Activate veinminer?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I am using the latest FTB Unleashed and MC 1.5.2 and i cannot get veinminer to work. I have put the mod in the enabled window. I have been looking for a config file but all i got is a .jar.I have set the enable veinminer hotkey on a free key (b) but cannot get these veins to mine at once. So how do i get this mod to work with FTB?

Here are some logs containing veinminer:

```
FTB Launcher logs:
2014-12-15 10:55:09 [SEVERE] [ForgeModLoader] The mcmod.info file in VeinMiner.0.4_MC1.5.2.jar cannot be parsed as valid JSON. It will be ignored

2014-12-15 10:55:09 [INFO] [VeinMiner] Activating mod VeinMiner

2014-12-15 10:56:34 [INFO] [Minecraft-Client] [CHAT] VeinMiner set to use keybind ('auto')
```

Comment: Only Linux has you to just place the mod in the appropriate directory.  Windows requires you to double click it.

Answer (score -1):

Vein miner is at start set to a mode, which it says in the chat, do not know however how to change said mode.

Comment: If you are adding something but not fixing the problem, add a comment, not an answer. Also, we work on research efforts, I did a simple google search and found how to change the mode, found [here}[https://minecraft.curseforge.com/projects/veinminer/pages/using-veinminer]. Next time work towards doing some research and trying to write a higher quality answer.